# Is it possible that a project can ONLY be build by MS Visual c++ express?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, netbeans, compiler-construction

I'm using a robotic software that comes with a SDK and allows me to write my own code, build it and add the generated "dll" and "kab" files to the bin directory of the software. By doing so, I'm able to add my own algorithms and new features the software (or maybe another SDK that I can not remember).

It uses their SDK, windows SDK and Cmake but the problem is in their documentation it's written that I can ONLY use Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 and nothing else! I tried with Microsoft visual studio 2008 and I failed.

Is it possible that somehow I have to use only msvc8? Is it because of some specific compilers of msvc8? If so, *is there anyway that I can use those compilers with Netbeans* (this msvc8 is extremely disappointing :/ )

Comment: "I tried with Microsoft visual studio 2008 and I failed." - an error message, a crash, nasal demons? What happened?

Comment: @DCoder, no error on the build but after I launch the software and try to run my "Added algorithm", it crashed.

Comment: Did the exact same build work on VS2005 (that is, did you rule out any bug in your own code)? That would be quite strange, does the documentation provide any justification for this? Does compilation produce any warnings, does the code rely on some undefined/implementation defined behaviour? What software is this (is it possible for someone else to try and reproduce this situation on their system)?

Comment: @DCoder, Yes it did (the build was successful in both 2005 and 2008. But software crashed when I copied dll file generated by 2008 into it's bin directory). My initial guess was that, this has something to with the licensing of the software (the one that I've received is for msvc8) but it made no sense.
The software is a robotics motion planning and it's a Proprietary software and I am given a special license for testing of an algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities -

Visual c++ 2005 and 2008 have different run time libraries.
If you are calling functions that have simple types as parameters then there isn't a problem but if you pass more complex types then the definitions of those types could have changed between versions. For example if a function takes std::string as a parameter you'll be creating it using one version of the class but trying to use it in code compiled using a different version of the class which will fail if it's different in any way that matters. I have no idea if that affects std::string but it might affect something you are using.

The other is memory allocation. Both parts are compiled with different run time libraries, so memory allocated in one won't be known to the other. If you new some memory in your dll and the main program tries to free it, it will have no idea about that memory and fail. This doesn't just apply to memory you allocate with new yourself, it can apply to any class that allocated memory itsself.

It is possible to write addon dlls using a different version of the compiler but you need to be very careful to only use types that work, and organise your memory allocation properly. Whether this is possible will depend on what the required interface is

edit: To answer your other question, the windows compilers all come with a compiler command line called "cl" which I'm sure you could invoke from netbeans although I don't use it so I can't tell you how